# JavaScript function loop elements in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am looking to find the solution to the below problem I have.

I have two arrays,

1. Data - Data array contains all data elements
2. Calculations - Calculation array elements refers to the data array elements and the calculation to build

I am trying to build a function that can loop through each of the calculation array items and returns a new array, with the expected result like the [mynewarray] below.

```
  data: [
    { id: 1, name: "item 1", value: 2 },
    { id: 2, name: "item 2", value: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: "item 3", value: 4 },
    { id: 4, name: "item 4", value: 5 },
    { id: 5, name: "item 5", value: 6 },
  ],

  //array with calculation to be applied ...
  calculations: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "cal 1",
      calc: [
        { id: 1, type: "field", value: 1 }, //refers to data array element with id 1
        { id: 2, type: "operator", value: "+" }, // operator value
        { id: 3, type: "field", value: 3 }, //refers to data array element with id 3
      ],
      //expected result value is 2+4
    },

    {
      id: 2,
      name: "cal 2",
      calc: [
        { id: 1, type: "calc", value: 1 }, //refers to calculation array element with id 1
        { id: 2, type: "operator", value: "+" }, // operator value
        { id: 3, type: "field", value: 4 }, //refers to data array element with id 4
      ],
      //expected result value is (2+4)+5
    },

    {
      id: 3,
      name: "cal 3",
      calc: [
        { id: 1, type: "field", value: 3 }, //refers to the data array element with id 3
        { id: 2, type: "operator", value: "+" }, // operator value
        { id: 3, type: "calc", value: 1 }, // refers to the calculation array element with id 1 
        { id: 4, type: "operator", value: "*" }, // operator value
        { id: 5, type: "calc", value: 2 }, // refers to the calculation array element with id 2 
      ],
      //expected result value is 4+(2+4)*((2+4)+5)
    },

    {
      id: 4,
      name: "cal 4",
      calc: [
        { id: 1, type: "calc", value: 3 }, // refers to the calculation array element with id 3
        { id: 2, type: "operator", value: "*" }, // operator value
        { id: 3, type: "calc", value: 2 }, // refers to the calculation array element with id 2
      ],

      //expected result value is (4+(2+4)*((2+4)+5))*((2+4)+5)
    },
  ],

//output array
 mynewarray: [
    { id: 1, value: "2+4"},  //return value from calculation 1
    { id: 2, value: "(2+4)+5"}, //return value from calculation 2
    { id: 3, value: "4+(2+4)*((2+4)+5)" }, //return value from calculation 3
    { id: 4, value: "(4+(2+4)*((2+4)+5))*((2+4)+5)"} //return value from calculation 4
  ],
```

Comment: { id: 1, value: "2+4"} does not make any sense from the data. The first object - data, with id 1 does not mention number '2' or '4' for 2+4, only number '1'. Where is 2? Calculations, first item id 1 has value 1, not 2? Where is '2' and where is '4'? Where is the logic for this first id?

Comment: the first object - data, with id 1 does not mention number '2' or '4' for 2+4, only number '1'. Where is 2?  2 is the value of element with id 1.
the id is a reference, we use the value field

Comment: Where is your attempt to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I am adding you can use the `map` function if you want such as `new map` and its code... The following link goes to its documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Hope it helps you and next time give more details about what you want...

Happy to help you!